# How to use live555 to streaming video?

Tags: c++, qt, video-streaming, live555

I use C++ with Qt to create a project to streaming video from KIT armTiny6410 to Laptop. I use live555 to do it. This is the Thread to streaming file. But I don't know what I need to include because when I compile I get these errors:

> error: 'TaskScheduler' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'scheduler' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'BasicTaskScheduler' has not been declared
>   error: 'UsageEnvironment' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'env' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'BasicUsageEnvironment' has not been declared
>   error: 'UserAuthenticationDatabase' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'authDB' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'RTSPServer' was not declared in this scope
>   error: 'rtspServer' was not declared in this scope

```
void ThreadStream::run()
{
    // Begin by setting up our usage environment:
    TaskScheduler* scheduler = BasicTaskScheduler::createNew();
    UsageEnvironment* env = BasicUsageEnvironment::createNew(*scheduler);

    UserAuthenticationDatabase* authDB = NULL;
    #ifdef ACCESS_CONTROL
    // To implement client access control to the RTSP server, do the following:
    authDB = new UserAuthenticationDatabase;
    authDB->addUserRecord("username1", "password1"); // replace these with real strings
    // Repeat the above with each <username>, <password> that you wish to allow
    // access to the server.
    #endif

    // Create the RTSP server.  Try first with the default port number (554),
    // and then with the alternative port number (8888):
    RTSPServer* rtspServer;
    portNumBits rtspServerPortNum = 554;
    rtspServer = DynamicRTSPServer::createNew(*env, rtspServerPortNum, authDB);
    if (rtspServer == NULL) {
        rtspServerPortNum = 8888;
        rtspServer = DynamicRTSPServer::createNew(*env, rtspServerPortNum, authDB);
    }
    if (rtspServer == NULL) {
        QString msg = "Failed to create RTSP server";
        emit notifyMessage(msg);
        exit(1);
    }
    QString msge = "LIVE555 Media Server\n";
    char* urlPrefix = rtspServer->rtspURLPrefix();
    msge += "Play streams from this server using the URL\n\t"
        +  QString(urlPrefix) + "<filename>\nwhere <filename> is a file present in the current directory.\n"
        + "Each file's type is inferred from its name suffix:\n"
        + "\t\".264\" => a H.264 Video Elementary Stream file\n"
        + "\t\".aac\" => an AAC Audio (ADTS format) file\n"
        + "\t\".ac3\" => an AC-3 Audio file\n"
        + "\t\".amr\" => an AMR Audio file\n"
        + "\t\".dv\" => a DV Video file\n"
        + "\t\".m4e\" => a MPEG-4 Video Elementary Stream file\n"
        + "\t\".mkv\" => a Matroska audio+video+(optional)subtitles file\n"
        + "\t\".mp3\" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Audio file\n"
        + "\t\".mpg\" => a MPEG-1 or 2 Program Stream (audio+video) file\n"
        + "\t\".ts\" => a MPEG Transport Stream file\n"
        + "\t\t(a \".tsx\" index file - if present - provides server 'trick play' support)\n"
        + "\t\".wav\" => a WAV Audio file\n"
        + "\t\".webm\" => a WebM audio(Vorbis)+video(VP8) file\n";

    emit notifyMessage(msge);

    env->taskScheduler().doEventLoop(); // does not return
}
```

My library of live555 in: /urs/lib/live
Please help me! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You need to include these three files which are there in folder **liveMedia/include**, **BasicUsageEnvironment/include** and **groupsock/include** folder of the source code directory

```
#include <liveMedia.hh>
#include <BasicUsageEnvironment.hh>
#include <GroupsockHelper.hh>
```

Comment: i did, but i got errors: liveMedia.hh no such file or directory; BasicUsageEnviroment no such file or directory. In file .pro of Qt project i add: LIBS += /usr/local/lib/live/liveMedia/libliveMedia.a \
            /usr/local/lib/live/BasicUsageEnvironment/libBasicUsageEnvironment.a \
            /usr/local/lib/live/UsageEnvironment/libUsageEnvironment.a \
            /usr/local/lib/live/groupsock/libgroupsock.a \. Please check for me, thank you!

Comment: make sure you file are there in the include directory